# VLC always transparent when using Compton

Tags: vlc, manjaro, fluxbox, compton

In Manjaro Fluxbox 15.10 the compositing manager Compton makes VLC in default interface to be transparent when playing even if on-top

[image]

or even in full-screen:

[image]

If I kill Compton, VLC looks normal.

With a custom skin there is no transparency (and using an external skin themes is the only way for now).

Comment: stackexchange is not the right place to report fluxbox-bugs. use sf.net/projects/fluxbox

Comment: @akira - in fact was not a bug, but a setting. I have an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Source](https://forum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=27152.msg229518#msg229518)

Access the window menu by right clicking or Alt-Space.

There can be set the transparency for the program. If you select 'Remember>transparency' it will stay like that when you open VLC the next time.